# Choose non Blank field

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, syntax

I have a sharepoint list with multiple calculated fields. I am looking to roll the fields into one by choosing a final status. There are 6 columns. I want the formula to look at all six columns and display the value of the ONE column that is NOT blank.

I'm sure this is easier than I am thinking, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with the `IF` and `ISBLANK` functions.

Assuming you have 3 columns here `Project_A`, `Project_B`, `Project_C`, here will be the formula. Just keep going with the IFs and sort them by priority (in the event if you have multiple blank columns, which column will show value first)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Project_A),
    IF(ISBLANK(Project_B), 
        IF(ISBLANK(Project_C), 
            "all blanks"
            , [Project_C])
        , [Project_B])
    , [Project_A])
```